# Reading and Validate CSV file in springboot

Tags: java, spring-boot, csv, spring-data-jpa, java-io

I am reading and validating data stored in .csv file in springboot.I am able to get the content of .csv file. Also I want to validate the data stored in file for that I need some extra attribute apart from file content. If I am uploading file from web page I can see the extra attributes needed . But If I uploading file from postman only file content is coming not the other required attribute. Its migration work where I am migrating code from .net to java. If I am uploading file through .NET web from I am getting below content which includes .csv file contents and other attribute but while developing same in Java through postman i can see the content of .csv file which is highlighted under RED line.
[image]

For validating .csv data I am using below java code including regular expression.

```
public class MultipartParser {
   // private static final Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(MultipartParser.class);

    public boolean success = false;
    public String name;
    public  String variableType;
    public String taxelid;
    public String text;
    public String contentType;
    public String fileName;

    public boolean ignoreFirstLine;

    public MultipartParser(){}
    public MultipartParser(MultipartFile stream){
        this.parse(stream);
    }
    public void parse(MultipartFile stream) {
        ///logger.info("Inside parser");

        try {
            String content = new String(stream.getBytes(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
            System.out.println("CONTENT::"+content);
            int delimiterEndIndex = content.indexOf("\r\n");

            if (delimiterEndIndex > -1)
            {
                String delimiter = content.substring(0, content.indexOf("\r\n"));
                // Look for Content-Type
                Pattern re = Pattern.compile("(?<=Content\\-Type:)(.*?)(?=\r\n\r\n)");
                Matcher contentTypeMatch = re.matcher(content);

                // Look for filename
                re = Pattern.compile("(?<=filename\\=\"\")(.*?)(?=\"\")");
                Matcher filenameMatch = re.matcher(content);

                // Look for variable
                re = Pattern.compile("(?<=name\\=\"\"variable\"\"\r\n\r\n)(.*?)(?=\r\n)");
                Matcher variableMatch = re.matcher(content);

                re = Pattern.compile("(?<=name\\=\"\"taxelid\"\"\r\n\r\n)(.*?)(?=\r\n)");
                Matcher taxelidMatch = re.matcher(content);

                // Look for name
                re = Pattern.compile("(?<=name\\=\"\"cgname\"\"\r\n\r\n)(.*?)(?=\r\n)");
                Matcher cgnameMatch = re.matcher(content);

                re = Pattern.compile("(?<=name\\=\"\"text\"\"\r\n\r\n)(.*?)(?=\r\n)");
                Matcher cgtextMatch = re.matcher(content);

                if (contentTypeMatch.matches() && filenameMatch.matches()){
                        this.variableType = variableMatch.group();
                        this.ignoreFirstLine = true;
                        this.name = cgnameMatch.group();
                        this.taxelid = taxelidMatch.group();
                        this.text = cgtextMatch.group();
                        this.success = true;
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            //logger.error("Error whilr reading Multipart file:"+e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getVariableType() {
        return variableType;
    }

    public void setVariableType(String variableType) {
        this.variableType = variableType;
    }

    public String getTaxelid() {
        return taxelid;
    }

    public void setTaxelid(String taxelid) {
        this.taxelid = taxelid;
    }

    public String getText() {
        return text;
    }

    public void setText(String text) {
        this.text = text;
    }

    public String getContentType() {
        return contentType;
    }

    public void setContentType(String contentType) {
        this.contentType = contentType;
    }

    public String getFileName() {
        return fileName;
    }

    public void setFileName(String fileName) {
        this.fileName = fileName;
    }

    public boolean isIgnoreFirstLine() {
        return ignoreFirstLine;
    }

    public void setIgnoreFirstLine(boolean ignoreFirstLine) {
        this.ignoreFirstLine = ignoreFirstLine;
    }

    public boolean isSuccess() {
        return success;
    }

    public void setSuccess(boolean success) {
        this.success = success;
    }
}
```

Can anyone please tell me how can I get other attributes apart from file content in Postman or what settings I need to do it Postman to get other attributes need to pass the regular expression.

Regatds,
Prabhash